# How to implement a init method for NSArrayController subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I create a class: `MyArrayController`, which is a subclass of `NSArrayController` and bind the it to a table.

I need to pass a person object to `MyArrayController` object, like using method:

```
-initWithPerson:(Person *)person;
```

but because `MyArrayController` is created automatically (because I don't alloc it explicitly, I think it is created by Cocoa automatically), I can't get the object of MyArrayController or init it explicitly.

What can I do to set a person object to MyArrayController?

Comment: What do you mean by "passing a person object" to your array controller?  Do you want to add that object to the controller's arranged  objects?

Comment: This is just like chat transcript program, which has two tables: table 1 is person list, when I click a person will pop up a window which display table 2 showing the chat transcript. I implement MyArrayController for table 2, table 2 just use person's name to display on the column 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to do this is not to use an `NSArrayController` subclass. From your description you are not trying to change the behavior of `NSArrayController` you are just trying to specify its content. The way to do this is to put an `NSArrayController` in your nib file and bind it to your table. Add an `IBOutlet` to your `NSWindowController` or `NSViewController` that is bound to the `NSArrayController`. Create and pre-populate an `NSArray` with the content you want to display in the table. Then in your `awakeFromNib` or `windowDidLoad` method you call `setContent:` to set the content array for the `NSArrayController` to the `NSArray` you created. Roughly like:

```
    IBOutlet NSArrayController *myArrayController;

    NSArray *contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:person];
    [myArrayController setContent:contentArray];
```